# Can PHP edit the javascript code before it executes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Is it possible to edit javascript code so that before it executes on page load I can inject few code changes through PHP. I want to use PHP so that changes happen on the server before page is loaded onto client side.

For example, this is what I have:

```
<script>
    video38.addParm("<param name='FlashVars' value='file=abc&fullscreen=true&width=440&height=241&'>")
</script>
```

And this is what I want:

```
<script>
    video38.addParm("<param name='FlashVars' value='file=abc&fullscreen=true&width=440&height=241&oneMoreParameter=paramValue'>")
</script>
```

I tried this with jquery but because this is flash, once it is loaded then adding parameter doesn't do anything. That's why I thought doing it in PHP because it executes on server side.

Any help on this will be great.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: The difference is (I think) that the top one has a line at the top and bottom and the bottom one has a line only at the bottom @putvande

Comment: How are you generating this code now? @UdayaSri, no AJAX won't do it if you read the question.

Comment: php process the html. it will load content which you provide by php you can change it in the file directly

Comment: how about write the data you need in a data-attribute with php and read it using js? or if you wanna access some dynamic server information use an ajax request.

Comment: the javascript code is generating through a software..hence I can't edit it directly... I can insert php script.

Comment: 2nd code has one extra parameter in the end: &oneMoreParameter=paramValue

Answer (score 0):

Take a look below:

```
<?php
  $test = 'test';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var test = '<?php echo $test; ?>';
</script>
```

Hope, this will be helpful to you!

Comment: I can't edit the javascript directly as it is auto-generated by a software. That's why I need PHP to edit it before it gets executed.

Answer (score -1):

```
        $ob = ob_start();
        //EXECUTE YOUR CODE HERE, THE PAGE AND STUFF e.g. include('./file.html');
        $pi = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $js = <<<'EOD'
video38.addParm("<param name='FlashVars' value='file=abc&fullscreen=true&width=440&height=241&oneMoreParameter=paramValue'>");
EOD;
        $pi = preg_replace("@video38.addParm(.*?);@s", $js, $pi);
        echo $pi;
```

Comment: my html/javascript is auto-generated and i have no control over that. so don't know how to use your code?

Comment: @suneelverma in "//EXECUTE" part you do include('./pathtohtmlfile.html');

Comment: i've included the html filename... but it still doesn't show in the source code when i run it from the local server.. not even when i inspect element in chrome

Comment: @suneelverma could you try again? I've edited my answer.